# Access multiple Connection Managers in SSIS 2012 Execute SQL Task

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

I have an SSIS 2012 project which consists of one Execute SQL Task. The package must be deployed to a SQL Server so that it can run independent of user intervention. The T-SQL accesses two different SQL servers, like this:

```
INSERT INTO Server1.MyDatabase1.dbo.MyTable1
SELECT * FROM Server2.MyDatabase2.dbo.MyTable2 T2
WHERE T2.MyField2 NOT IN (SELECT MyField1 FROM Server1.MyDatabase1.dbo.MyTable1)
```

This works fine, but is obviously not very portable. I'd like to create two Connection Managers for Server1 and Server2 and refer to the values of the Connection Managers in the T-SQL. The Connection Managers are also contained in the Project.params, so I could use the Project.params instead. At any rate, is it possible to refer to Connection Managers or the Project.params in an Execute SQL Task? Or can I create variables from them and reference the variables in the Execute SQL Task? Or do I need to go about this in a completely different way, such as pulling both data sets in via Data Flow Tasks and then processing them?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use variables:

- Variable1:  holds the name of Server1
- Variable2:  holds the name of
  Server2
- Variable3:  holds your entire SQL Statement and is    constructed
  using Variables 1 & 2.

Then your execute SQL task uses Variable 3 as its source.

However, the statement will only be run on one ConnectionManager, so it will have to be one that can run the statement using the 4-part naming convention as shown in your question.

Comment: Thanks! So I'd have to go in an change the variable values if I want to deploy to a different set of servers, right? I'm trying to avoid that, if possible.

Comment: You can set the variables with Parameters, or with the .config files that live on the different servers, so that you don't need a different version of the package on each server.   The way you phrased it in your question, it sounds like a solution that lets you use parameters to create variables that you can reference in your Execute SQL task would be acceptable.

Comment: I've added some more information to my original question: this package must be deployed to a SQL Server and run independently of any user interaction. And, when I say "Parameter", I mean the Project.params that get created in SSIS 2012 which represent the different project connections, *not* the Parameter mapping in an Execute SQL Task. What I want to do is have the variables mapped to the Project.params so I only need to change the latter (which I'd do anyway) when I move the package to a different set of servers. Thanks! But I'm going to look into your config file suggestion, thank you!